# How to import a font installed with NPM?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

I have a React project where I installed Roboto font doing 'npm install font-roboto'. I'd like to import that from my main.js file instead of referencing a CDN in index.html.

What would be the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently you can import it doing the following in the main.js

```
import '../node_modules/font-roboto/dist/styles/roboto.min.css';
```

UPDATE: As noted in the comments, the following also works.

```
import 'font-roboto/dist/styles/roboto.min.css';
```

Comment: If you have your paths set up correctly, you shouldn't need the `../node_modules` bit.

Comment: good, and for more note, if you have the path you should put './font-roboto/dist/styles/roboto.min.css', it was a fixed problem for me.

Comment: @AsmaaAlmadhoun - If you have to put `./` for stuff in `node_modules`, then you have things set up incorrectly.

Comment: right, but I meant if he downloaded the file and have it out of node_module as an external file in his app folder, at this time he should put './' .. thanks for commenting, it makes my comment becomes more clear with explaining my idea